# Is there any way to get 2 sided FPC with stiffener?

Tags: pcb, connector, design, fpc, flexible

We need to design an FPC board that consists of components like mezzanine connectors that are centered on 2 sides, top and bottom layers. We have concerns about attaching the FPC board to the main PCB without damaging the connectors. So is there a way to make a stronger FPC board with some material like a stiffener, while also placing components on both sides?

Note: We know we can design rigid-flex PCB but it is more expensive than FPC boards.

Comment: That does seem like precisely what rigid-flex was designed for - I would be surprised if other methods (not sure what they would be) were not equally as expensive.

Answer (score 0):

You can have your boards made from aluminum, I believe the Gerber files are the same.  They are quite sturdy and are great for getting rid of heat. The only downfall I see is they may be a little harder to solder depending on your setup. You can check the pros and cons on line. Since I do not know our application I do not know what parameters to check.

Answer (score 0):

Some flat flex manufacturers can cut holes in stiffener (I've done holes in stiffener through PCB way before). Is this provide them the board file and they can cut the holes in it. I don't know if they would balk that exposed copper in the middle of the stiffener.

What I would do is I would create a stiffener layer on the flat flex and cut holes for the components you could probably do this on one side of the flat flex only. The problem that you will run into though is assembling the "PCB" is with the stiffener in the way you aren't going to be able to get a stencil or a solder mask for a solder paste process. So if you have a lot of components or small component pitches that won't be very viable option.

Another option would be to create channels of stiffener around the components, anyway a few things to think about about. But if you want to get creative you're going to have to think through all the processes of flat flex manufacturer and PCB assembly to come up with a viable process.